# Compact extensions for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am using more than 10 extensions in Chrome. All those are lined beside my omni box and it had messed up with the simplicity of Chrome. Is there a Chrome extension to put all the other extension inside it and which appears as a special icon beside the omni box, which on clicking it brings all the other extensions available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all you have to do is slide the omnibox to the wrench and they will collapse
[image]

and this is without an extension.